# PHP compare values in a single array and output the difference

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
$rowarray(
[0] => [PID] => 97162 [TID] => 340 [StatsID] => 49678
[1] => [PID] => 97165 [TID] => 340 [StatsID] => 49673
[2] => [PID] => 97167 [TID] => 340 [StatsID] => 49675
[3] => [PID] => 97162 [TID] => 340 [StatsID] => 49679
)
```

Then my code looks like this:

```
$cntr=0;
foreach($rowarray as $row)
{
 echo "<tr><td>$row[PID] $row[TID] $row[StatsID] </td></tr>";
$cntr++;
}
```

Two things I want to do I want to be able not print the duplicates in the array but print the additional column that has a different value. So my desired output would look like this.

97162 340 49678 49679

97165 340 49673

97167 340 49675

I started out with the array_unique() but that only returned:

97162 340 49678

Comment: If this is data retrieved from a database query, you can use SELECT DISTINCT rather than simply SELECT

Comment: It is but the distinct doesn't display anything based on my statement. Also it would remove the entire row and not give me the different value.

Comment: Need more details... is it only the StatsID that changes?

Comment: yes that is the only value that changes

Comment: If your data is returned from a database, you can use a simple `GROUP BY` and an aggregate function on your `StatsID` column.

Comment: Kenaniah please elaborate with your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming only the StatsID changes (not clear from the question)

```
$map = array();
foreach($rowarray as $row){
    $k = $row["PID"] . '-' . $row["TID"];
    if( !isset( $map[$k] ) ){
        $map[$k] = array();
    }
    array_push( $map[$k], $row["StatsId"] );
}


foreach($map as $k=>$v){
    $row = explode( '-', $k );
    echo "<tr><td>$row[0] $row[1] " . implode( " ", $v ) . " </td></tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd do:

- Start by sorting the array (using `usort` to sort by PID, then by TID)
- Initialize "last" variables (`$last_PID` and `$last_TID`). They will store the respective values in the loop
- In the loop, first compare the "current" variables to the "last" ones, if they're the same then just echo the StatsID value.
- If they're not the same, output the `<tr>` (but not the final `</tr>`, so the first part of the loop can add more StatsID values if necessary)
- Still inside the loop, after outputting everything, update the "last" variables.
- After the loop, output the final `</tr>`

This may not be optimal, but I'm pretty sure it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Transfer the `$rowarray` structure into a map of maps of arrays, like this:

```
$rowarray = array(
    array('PID' => 97162, 'TID' => 340, 'StatsID' => 49678),
    array('PID' => 97165, 'TID' => 340, 'StatsID' => 49673),
    array('PID' => 97167, 'TID' => 340, 'StatsID' => 49675),
    array('PID' => 97162, 'TID' => 340, 'StatsID' => 49679)
);

$keys = array();

foreach ($rowarray as $row) {
    if (!is_array(@$keys[$row['TID']])) {
        $keys[$rowarray['TID']] = array();
    }

    if (!is_array(@$keys[$row['TID']][$row['PID']])) {
        $keys[$row['TID']][$row['PID']] = array();
    }

    $keys[$row['TID']][$row['PID']][] = $row['StatsID'];
}

foreach ($keys as $pid => $pid_arr) {
    foreach ($pid_arr as $tid => $tid_arr) {
        echo "<tr><td>$tid $pid " . implode(' ', $tid_arr) . "</td></tr>";
    }
}
```

[See this code in action](http://ideone.com/M9Te9)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the only way to do this would be to loop through the array creating a new unique array as you go.

```
$unique = array();
foreach ($row as $value)
{
    $key = $value['PID'];
    if (isset($unique[$key]))
    {
        $unique[$key]['StatsID'] .= ' ' . $value['StatsID'];
    }
    else
    {
        $unique[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Now, $unique would give you the results you're looking for and you can loop through the unique array and output your results (I also added your counter if needed):

```
$count = count($unique);
foreach ($unique as $row)
{
    echo "<tr><td>{$row['PID']} {$row['TID']} {$row['StatsID']} </td></tr>";
}
```